# Display Html Content in Edittext in Android

Tags: android

```
String msg = < table >< tr >< td > < b >Some text here</ b ></ td ></ tr ></ table >;
EditText txtMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
txtMsg.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

where `txtMsg` is the String in which I have written Html tags but  it give me simple text I want it in Html format in Android.

Comment: Would you please clarify what do you mean by `HTML format`?

Comment: do you want the text to display bold?

Comment: Html format means content into table which can be set in edittext dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to call `Html.fromHtml()`, passing it your HTML string, and pass the results to `setText()` on your `EditText`. However, that will not support `<table>`, `<tr>`, or `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Html.fromHtml() only supports a small subset of html tags. If you want to have support for additional tags, you have to add them manually.

Comment: thanks for your reply CommonsWare and danijoo...can you give me some demo code...it will help me.